# How to save (or convert) HTML content as RTE parsable content in Extbase?

Tags: html, typo3, converters, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I'm retrieving 3rd party html in my controller which I'd like to save (or convert) as `RTE parsable content`.

For example:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vel tristique ex. Sed sit amet tempor sapien, at euismod erat.</p>
<p>Sed et leo sit amet lorem consectetur ultricies. Aenean iaculis non ligula aliquam pulvinar.</p>
```

Is parsed incorrectly when using `f:format.html` and results in:

```
<p class="bodytext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vel tristique ex. Sed sit amet tempor sapien, at euismod erat.</p>
<p class="bodytext">&nbsp;</p>
```

`f:format.raw` will not be the solution for me since I need to translate hyper links to `RTE <link>` tags also.

So is there a way to convert or save my (3rd party WYSIWYG) content so it will be parsed correctly by `f:format.html`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is the `parseFuncTSPath` Parameter. Try this:

```
<f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc">... your HTML here ...</f:format.html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create or use **Rte View Helper** to get the proper content rendering. For Creating view helper take [reference](https://forge.typo3.org/attachments/3579/RteViewHelper.php). You can download RTE view helper from **[here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140627183631/http://forge.typo3.org:80/attachments/3579/RteViewHelper.php)**